# How to call fortran module helper subroutine in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran

I am new to Fortran. I wonder how I can call a module (helper) function in GDB when debugging a file that uses the module. I tried

```
p MODULENAME::SUBROUTINE_NAME(ARGUMENTS)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Was there an error, or did it just not do what you expected?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't remember now. It has been over a year. I can try a similar thing and let you know sometime. I likely needed it to call a print function and it didn't work and I just ended up baking it in the code, instead of calling from gdb.